# Number of paths in a randomly labeled complete graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I have a complete graph with `n` vertices, set `W` (let's say `W = {1,2,3}`) and a path `path` (let's also say `path = {1,2,3}`). Every edge of my graph is randomly labeled with one of the elements of the set `W`.

For better understanding, that's one of the [examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTrrT.png) for `n = 5`.

What I need is to find the number of paths `path` in this graph. [All paths for the graph above (11 paths in total).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61xoR.png)

I've developed some kind of algorithm for finding this paths but I want to know are there any chance to improve it? Or maybe I can find this paths in a complete different, more efficient way?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

std::vector<int> path{1,2,3}; // paths we are looking for

void finderRec(std::vector<std::tuple<int,int,int>>& edges, int& p, int k, int& TotalNumber){
    for (int i = 0; i < edges.size(); ++i){
        if (std::get<2>(edges[i]) == path[k] && (p == std::get<0>(edges[i]) || p == std::get<1>(edges[i]))){
            if (p == std::get<0>(edges[i]) && k + 1 < path.size())
                finderRec(edges, std::get<1>(edges[i]), k + 1, TotalNumber);
            else if (p == std::get<1>(edges[i]) && k + 1 < path.size())
                finderRec(edges, std::get<0>(edges[i]), k + 1, TotalNumber);
            else
                TotalNumber++;
        }
    }
}

int pathFinder(std::vector<int>& path, std::vector<std::tuple<int,int,int>>& edges){
    int TotalNumber = 0;
    for (auto& x: edges)
        if (std::get<2>(x) == path[0]){
            finderRec(edges, std::get<0>(x), 1, TotalNumber);
            finderRec(edges, std::get<1>(x), 1, TotalNumber);
            }
    return TotalNumber;
}

std::vector<std::tuple<int,int,int>> generateGraph(int& n, std::vector<int>& W){
    std::vector<std::tuple<int,int,int>> edges;
    int m = (n * (n - 1)) / 2; // number of edges in a complete graph
    int j = 0; // number of the vertex next to the vertex i
    int random;
    int len = W.size(); // length of vector W
    int sel_elem;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
        j = i + 1;
        while (j <= n){
            random = rand() % len;
            sel_elem = W[random];
            edges.push_back({i,j,sel_elem});
            j++;
        }
    }
    return edges;
}

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << "\n";
    int n; // number of vertices
    std::cout << "Input the number of vertices n: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> W{1,2,3}; // set of labels
    std::vector<std::tuple<int,int,int>> edges = generateGraph(n, W);
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Total number of paths = " <<  pathFinder(path, edges) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Prefer `struct` over `std::tuple` where possible

`std::tuple` has several drawbacks over declaring your own `struct`, the most notable one is that you can't name the tuple elements, instead you have to use `std::get<>` and remember which order you put the elements in. It's a little effort up front to declare a `struct`, but it will be much easier to work with, and since both the tuple as a whole and its members have names, it's almost self-documenting. Consider:

```
struct Edge {
    int from;
    int to;
    int label;
};
```

## Consider using type aliases

There are a lot of `int`s and vectors of things. It would be nice to give things distinct names; this helps document their purpose and can reduce the length of some type names, making the code easier to read. It also makes it easier later on to change the type of things by just changing the alias. Consider:

```
using Node = int;
using Label = int;

struct Edge {
    Node from;
    Node to;
    Label label;
};

using LabelSet = std::vector<Label>;
using Path = std::vector<Node>;
using Graph = std::vector<Edge>;
```

This way your code will start to look like this:

```
void finderRec(Graph& graph, Node p, Node k, int& TotalNumber) {
    for (auto& edge: graph) {
        if (edge.label == path[k] && (p == edge.from || p == edge.to)) {
            ...
```

## Use C++'s random number generators

Avoid `rand()`; it's a C function, it's not a very good random number generator, and you didn't even seed it so it produces the same sequence of "random" numbers every time you start your program. Using the modulo operator to limit the random numbers to a certain range is also not great, since it can introduce a bias in the numbers produced. Since C++11 the C++ standard library comes with some very good [random number generator facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), so prefer to use those instead:

```
std::random_device random_device;
std::default_random_engine random_engine(random_device());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> random_label(0, W.size() - 1);
...
sel_elem = W[random_label(random_engine)];
```

## Improving efficiency

Your algorithm is very slow for larger graphs, since each time it finds a suitable edge, it will recurse and scan through all the edges again until it completes a path. That's \$\mathcal{O}(E^3)\$ time complexity, where \$E\$ is the number of edges, which in itself is in the order of the number of nodes squared.

What would greatly help is if we didn't have to scan all the edges. If you would store the graph as an [adjecency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list), then in `finderRec()` you would only have to check the edges directly connected to the node `p`.

It might also be possible to gain some performance improvement by sorting the adjacency list on the label, such that you can easily find those edges your are really interested in. Whether that pays off probably depends on the size of the graph and the number of distinct labels.

## Avoid global variables

It's a bit weird that you have only `path` as a global variable. I would make this a parameter of `pathFinder()` and `finderRec()`. I recommend avoiding global variables where possible, as they can become problematic in larger projects, where they pollute the global namespace, and if they are not `const` they are unsafe if you have reentrant functions and multiple threads using them.

## Make variables and references `const` where appropriate

When you pass parameters by reference and they should not be changed, make them `const` references. This allows the compiler to optimize the code more, and will also catch programming errors if you accidentily do change some parameter that should have been kept unchanged.

## Make functions `static` where appropriate

Functions that are only used within the same source file should be made `static`. This avoids polluting the global namespace, and might allow the compiler to make more optimizations. `main()` itself should not be `static` though.

## Naming things

Try to avoid one-character names for variables, unless it's something very commonly used, like `i` and `j` for loop indices, or `x`/`y`/`z` for coordinates. I would suggest the following changes:

- `pathFinder()` -> `countPaths()`, as it only returns the number of paths found.
- `TotalNumber` -> `count`
- `n` -> `size`
- `edges` -> `graph`, especially if you change it from a list of edges to a list of nodes with adjacency lists
- `W` -> `labels`